# my html file in vscode will not let me add code to file

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[index.html file open in vscode not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAGDB.png)

I am having an issue. I created my index.html in my project folder and it won't let me add code to the html file. But now my js files and css files I can. Why? I have been trying to fix this for hours and I don't get it ive went back deleted folders and started over looked in settings, extensions, I am stumped. Please help me I am on a Mac. It just isn't making sense why I cannot code to the html file but I can the other ones.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your project with the html page open in your vs code editor?

Comment: I have edited my post with the picture

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it. And check output panel's various channels for error messages.